# Mockito ambiguous method call: any() matches class and object

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I need to mock this code

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(message, m -> {
    m.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().put("type", HEADER);
    return m;
});
```

I my test I write

```
doNothing().when(rabbitTemplate).convertAndSend(anyObject(), any(MessagePostProcessor.class));
```

There is an error

[image]

Any ideas about workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `anyObject()`. Try specifying the type.

```
doNothing().when(rabbitTemplate).convertAndSend(Mockito.any(String.class), any(MessagePostProcessor.class));
```

Comment: good idea, it works like this `doNothing().when(rabbitTemplate).convertAndSend(any(Object.class), any(MessagePostProcessor.class));`
Thanks